# Unable to open Excel file after sending it via python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, smtp

I am sending an email with excel file as an attachment.
Everything is fine, but when I try to open excel file from email, I got an error:

[image]

I am not very familiar with python, what can be the problem here?

**Code below:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyodbc

import smtplib 
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart 
from email.mime.text import MIMEText 
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase 
from email import encoders 


fromaddr = "FromEmail"
toaddr = "ToEmail"

# instance of MIMEMultipart 
msg = MIMEMultipart() 

# storing the senders email address   
msg['From'] = fromaddr 

# storing the receivers email address  
msg['To'] = toaddr 

# storing the subject  
msg['Subject'] = "Sending Attachement"

# string to store the body of the mail 
body = "Hello, this is a test email!"

# attach the body with the msg instance 
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain')) 

# open the file to be sent  
filename = "AZ.xlsx"
attachment = open('C:\\Users\\Folder\\AZ.xlsx',encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore')

# instance of MIMEBase and named as p 
p = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream') 

# To change the payload into encoded form 
p.set_payload((attachment).read()) 

# encode into base64 
encoders.encode_base64(p) 

p.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename) 

# attach the instance 'p' to instance 'msg' 
msg.attach(p) 

# creates SMTP session 
s = smtplib.SMTP('10.10.10.10: 25') 

# start TLS for security 
s.starttls() 

# Authentication 
#s.login(fromaddr, "password") 

# Converts the Multipart msg into a string 
text = msg.as_string() 

# sending the mail 
s.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text) 

# terminating the session 
s.quit()
```

Comment: How do you create the excel file in the first place?

Comment: always open in bytes mode - `open( ..., "rb")`. If you open in text mode then it converts chars "new line" and you get wrong file.

Comment: Perfect. Please, post an answer, I'd love to accept it. Thank you